# Keydown not called for objects inside an SKScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, keydown

I was working on a little game when I ran into a problem. I made a little test project in order to isolate the problem.

I have the following class:

```
class Sprite: SKSpriteNode {

    override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool { get { return true } }

    init() {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 100))
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    }

    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    
        position.x += 100
    
        print("keydown")
    
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

I create an instance of this class in the following scene:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool { get { return true } }

    let x = Sprite()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    
        anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
        addChild(x)
    
    }

    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    
        x.position.y += 50
    
    }

}
```

As you can see, I have a `keyDown` method in both classes. The one in `GameScene` gets called as I can clearly see the sprite (`x`) move upwards. The `keyDown` method in my `Sprite` class however, never gets called. I have searched the web and the only answer I've really found is that `acceptsFirstResponder` must be overridden and return `true`, but this doesn't help in my case. Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you turn off the acceptsFirstResponder in the GameScene class? It looks your problem is you have the scene and sprite both set to accept first responder, but only one of them can be the first responder. You have to pick one, the scene or the sprite.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my... I found a simple solution and I certainly don't know how I didn't think of it before.

Since `GameScene`'s `keyDown` method actually gets called, I just called the sprite's `keyDown` method from there and passed the argument:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let x = Sprite()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

        addChild(x)

    }

    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {

        x.position.y += 50
        x.keyDown(with: event)

    }

}
```

And it didn't require me to override any variables (I guess it's set to first responder by default - please correct me if this is false).